# How to convert Excel IF function into google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-conversion, iif-function

I converted an excel document into a google sheet but the formulas didn't tranfer correctly. Specifically the IF functions. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This was the original IF function in excel:
=IF(LEN(T4)=6,CEILING(T4,10)-1,IF(LEN(T4)<6,CEILING(T4,1)-0.01,IF(LEN(T4)=7,CEILING(T4,100)-1,"false")))

The number in T4 is 1,754.55

When converted it does not give me the same result. I should be getting a number but instead I get "false". If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's in `T4`?

Comment: That means that whatever is in `T4` has a `LEN` greater than `7`.

Comment: @BigBen it's the number 1,754.55

Comment: ... the length of that is `8`. Change the format to `Automatic`.